# Problema al instalar apache netbeans

Tags: netbeans, windows10, netbeans-11

descargué Apache netbeans 11 desde la página oficial y estoy tratando de correr el binario de 64 bits pero en consola no me sale nada y al correr me sale un mensaje indicando que no encuentra un JDK adecuado.

Tengo instalado Zulu 12, así que al correr en consola

```
java -version
```

obtengo

> openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu12.2+3-CA (build 12.0.1+12)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu12.2+3-CA (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)

No tengo configurada la variable `JAVA_HOME`.

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

> %JAVA_HOME%

pero mi Java está bien configurado

```
where javac
```

> C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-12\bin\javac.exe

¿Qué puedo hacer para correr mi netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para descartar problemas de configuración y asegurarte que tu JDK es compatible se puede hacer lo siguiente:

1. ir a la carpeta `etc` dentro del directorio de instalación
2. allí ubicar el archivo `netbeans.conf`
3. busca en los comentarios uno que indique la ubicacion del JDK

   ```
   # Default location of JDK:
   ```
4. cambiar `netbeans_jdkhome` a

   ```
   netbeans_jdkhome="C:/Program Files/Zulu/zulu-12/"
   ```

Como fuciona, al parecer es necesario configurar la variable `JAVA_HOME` **siempre**